# Cakephp 3 dynamically build contain

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, eager

How can I dynamically build the contain in the new cakephp 3 query builder. This is what I have now:

```
$query = $dbTable->find()
                ->select($contain['select']['fields'])
                ->contain(function($q) use($array,$contain){
                      $new = [];
                      foreach($array as $v){
                        if(isset($contain['contains'][$v])){
                          $fields = $contain['contains'][$v];
                          $new[$v] = $q->select($fields);
                         }
                      }
                      return $new;
                  });
```

But I am getting several errors with this:

```
Warning (2): Illegal offset type in isset or empty [CORE\src\ORM\EagerLoader.php, line 198]
Warning (2): strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given [CORE\src\ORM\EagerLoader.php, line 203]
Warning (2): Illegal offset type [CORE\src\ORM\EagerLoader.php, line 223]
Warning (2): Illegal offset type [CORE\src\ORM\EagerLoader.php, line 224]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by Lorenzo, that's not how it works, `contain()` doesn't accept callables, just look at the docs:

**http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Query.html#_contain**

Also your code would invoke `select()` multiple times on one and the same query, that wouldn't work anyways.

However, looking at your code it seems that you could simply make use of the `fields` option, ie build a simple array to pass to `contain()`. This is shown in the docs, the example however will trigger an error as it seems to be necessary to explicitly set the foreign key field too:

```
$query->contain([
    'Articles' => [
        'fields' => ['foreign_key_column_name', 'title']
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use contain with a closure inside. If you believe this is a good idea (I think it could be) then open a enhancement request on github.

Answer (score 0):

To get all fields in the table Articles do this in your controller.

```
$query = $this->modelName->find('all')
                   ->contain('Articles');
```

If you want a expecify field use this:

```
$query = $this->modelName->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'id',
    'valueField' => 'author.name'
])->contain(['Articles']);
```

To more informations about: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html